# URL Builder source/medium problem in facebook and google analytic

Tags: facebook, google-analytics

I have an issue in Facebook URL builder.

The issue is I have set in the parameter into URL builder that doesn't shown in Google analytic.

Set Campaign name : facebook
Campaign medium: CPC
Campaign name:FB-Traffic-Jan 2 - 31

But then it doesn't show as Facebook /CPC in Google Analytic.

Anyone knows what the problems???

http://www.xxxxxxxx.com/?utm_source=facebook&utm_medium=CPC&utm_campaign=FB-Traffic-Jan+2+-+31

Thank everyone in advance

Best Regards, 
Leon Hon

**google analytic screen cap**
[image]

**Facebook URL builder screen cap**
[image]

Comment: When you test this campaign URL by opening it in your browser, what is the end result in the address bar, when the page is loaded? E.g., is it possible, that a redirect drops your UTM parameters?

Comment: What is the full URL with query strings?
The screengrab seems to show that you are seeing Facebook as a source, can you update your channel groupings to correctly capture the traffic in the channel you expect?
Depending on the journey to the site your parameters might get dropped, try the chrome extension link redirect trace to understand the journey from link click to hitting the site.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/ or https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Hi AsomN

the following is the URL link generated:

http://www.xxxxxx.com/?utm_source=facebook&utm_medium=CPC&utm_campaign=FB-Traffic-Jan+2+-+31

Answer (score 0):

Surely it is not a problem of the values ​​of the UTM parameters, I just tried with my Property follow a link from Facebook with your UTM:

[image]

It is likely that a redirect will make you lose them (try to check the url in address bar when you open the site page by clicking on that Facebook link, probably you can't see the parameters).

If instead the parameters are present, try to wait for the data to be acquired in Analytics report and check in the report of source / medium.

Real-time reporting is not very reliable, especially for campaign values.

Comment: Hi Michele Pisani.  Thanks for the reply,

Comment: Hi Michele Pisani.  Thanks for the reply,



In fact I have waited a few days for the source/medium in the report view.  But none of them is showing as facebook/cpc that is why I have doubts on what did I do.

As in Dec, I did everything the same (Both in real time and acquisition report) showing CPC.    But in Jan, it throw everything back to Facebook/social.  Cause I can see a huge amount of user flow to facebook/social and CPC is none.  



if the UTM parameter is correct (and you have tried it).  I really have no idea, what goes wrong......

Comment: Do you have any filter on the view?